# Batch script xmgrace

Tags: mac

I am recently starting to use xmgrace software. It is great, but I have lots of graph to make(curves, histograms, gaussian..) with large quantity so I decided to learn to write a script for it...
I found out that this website has wonderful answers, and I would like to know, how to plot a curve with XYDY type, how to write the command?

READ SINGLE_SET "DATA.dat"
TYPE data_set_type xydy
...

This doesn't work, it gives two curve without data dots either the error bar.
I don't know if 'READ SINGLE_SET "DATA.dat"' is correct? Because each time  when I run this script, the terminal output as:
syntax error: READ SINGLE_SET "ops_pause_master_xmgrace"

However, I still get two curves like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyVE9.jpg)

and if I want to fit a non linear function to the curve, how to write the command, please?
Thank you for your attention, it would be great if someone could answer my questions.

Sincerely,
Jin